# ASP WebAPI Authentication with Javascript Client

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently developing an API based on the ASP WebAPI.  I'm currently looking at ways for authenticating users calling the API.  Currently users will need to login before they can make future API calls.  They will be able to login in from a JavaScript application which will try to post their credentials to the API and if that is successful, then they can other calls assuming they are authenticated.  I have looked at various way of authentication such as:
Basic Authentication,
Token Based Authentication,
Cookie Based Authentication

It seems that each has its pros and cons.
I'm looking for suggestion on the best authentication technique that will allow client side to login and make API calls.

Thanks.

Comment: Any authentication schema will allow your users to authenticate and then use your API. The question is what qualities do you expect from your authentication mechanism? Need content integrity verification? Have to scale? Don't want to host yourself? Don't want to store credentials? Require rich roles and membership support?

Comment: I'm certainly looking for quality and that one reason i have chosen the ASP WebApi for my API.  After some research, it seems that Cookie Based Authentication is the way to go.  the one restriction is that i'm getting a Cross Origin Error when accessing the API from a different domain.  For now i'm going to be hosting the client on the same domain, therefor it is not an issue, however in the future it could be an issue if i decide the API is open to the public which it will be which is why i'm going to also implement Token based authentication.

Comment: Web API 2 has a nice CORS support. See here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: I have specifically followed that example.  But it seems that implementing Cookie Based Authentication, you will not have to make such change.